# Microsoft Graph Get Teams Calls for all Tenant

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I need to get all my Tenant Teams call History.

To do that, I'm using ["getPstnCalls"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-getpstncalls?view=graph-rest-beta).
But I'm getting 0 results.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try the following API call and it worked for me:

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/callRecords/getPstnCalls(fromDateTime=2021-04-01,toDateTime=2021-03-01)

Comment: Please note that the fromDateTime and toDateTime values cannot be more than a date range of 90 days. If you used beyond that it won't provide any results; you can check the [same documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-getpstncalls?view=graph-rest-beta).

Comment: @rockxl1, Please let us know does that help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the Answer for better knowledge

Copying from @Dev comments

The fromDateTime and toDateTime values cannot be more than a date range of 90 days. If you used beyond that it won't provide any results; you can check the same [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-getpstncalls?view=graph-rest-beta).